# Querying query results

Tags: sql

If I have a query for example

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'HENRY';
```

thats returns say twenty results for HENRY that are identical.

Is there a way to then query the results of the original query to only return non duplicates.

This is a trivial example but basically I have a query where I am trying to perform a SELECT DISTINCT on a large data set. If I don't specify DISTINCT I get a relatively small and fast return of some duplicate data. Is there any logic in SQL I can apply to then perform a SELECT DISTINCT on those results. Essentially breaking up the query to reduce response times? Assume everything of value is indexed.

Thanks

Comment: The query does not say results are identical. Query just returns those records where FIRSTNAME is HENRY. Unless your definition of identical is equal FIRSTNAMEs, this query does not return identical.

Please put the table structure, sample data and what output are you expecting

Comment: This is a hypothetical query where all records that contain HENRY as the value for FIRSTNAME will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

To return the first of a group of records you can do something like this:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by firstname order by id) r
    FROM MY_TABLE 
    --WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'HENRY'
) x
where x.r = 1
```

If the records are exact duplicates, you're not worried about the first since they're all the same, so you just want distinct records:

```
SELECT distinct *
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'HENRY'
```

or to see how many duplicates:

```
SELECT *, count(*)-1 NoOfDuplicates
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'HENRY'
group by firstname, lastname --, ...
```

Comment: The SELECT DISTINCT results are essentially what I want. But running just SELECT DISTINCT is slow. What I am wondering is can I do a SELECT (without distinct), get the duplicates quickly and THEN perform a SELECT DISTINCT on those duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned that for the database to divide the data set up into those records which have a duplicate and those which do not is generally no more efficient than performing the actual distinct, unless the number of columns on which duplication occurs is very much less than the total number of columns.

In some cases of very wide tables where duplication exist only on a subset of columns and on a small proportion of the rows it *might* be more efficient to do something like:

```
select *
from   my_table t1
where  not exists (
         select null
         from   my_table t2
         where  t2.duplication_column = t1.duplication_column and
                t2.rowid              != t1.rowid)
union all
select distinct *
from   my_table t1
where  exists (
         select null
         from   my_table t2
         where  t2.duplication_column = t1.duplication_column and
                t2.rowid              != t1.rowid)
```

This would generally not be worth doing unless it avoided something very inefficient, like a very large sort spilling to disk.

Edit: modified the query

Comment: So I have a situation where if I do select distinct it will query a massive data set. But without distinct it will only return a small number of duplicates - less than 20 say. What I want to do is runt he select without the DISTINCT, get the duplicates (its faster). Then use the result of that query (duplicates and all) then run a select distinct on it - to get what I need.

Comment: The above method relies on being able to detect rows that do and do not need distincts applied to them. It would be easier to deal with your case if it was fully described, to be honest. The hypotheticals often do not work well.